# Timer Interval and Calendar Trigger of Notifications Possible?

Tags: swift, swift4

I would like to have the user choose the date and time that their notifications start (October 15, 2018 at 9:15 AM) AND choose how often they want the notification to show up (every 5, 7, 15, etc minutes). It appears after looking at Swift 4 documentation, this functionality is split up between UNCalendarNotificationTrigger and UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger. Is there any way to set up this functionality?

Comment: You can try using UNUserNotificationCenter. You can schedule the notifications every 5,7,15 etc minutes from the start time the user picked.

Comment: @Ashik I don't see where this can be done with UNUserNotificationCenter in the docs. What method should I be using?

Comment: Check this out. It's a good article: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/21/2/scheduling-notifications-unusernotificationcenter-and-unnotificationrequest

Comment: Just schedule  a single notification and once you receive that notification just schedule the next one